# Set CKEditor config dynamically

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor

I need to change one config setting in CKEditor config dynamically.

I'm writing a plugin which adds checkbox to CKEditor toolbar and upon checking/unchecking it - a `forcePasteAsPlainText` is being changed as true/false.

Issue is that config is being read on initiating CKEditor component and all changes later are being ignored. Is there a possible way to change value 'on the fly'?

Answer (score 4):

1. You can specif settings in config file that are default initializations for any editor created.

   ```
   CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
   config.forcePasteAsPlainText = false;
   ...
   }
   ```
2. You can override the config settings in this way so only the editor initialized will get these changes.

   ```
   CKEDITOR.replace('myEditor', { forcePasteAsPlainText: ture });
   ```
3. You can also use editor destroy and recreate with custom configs.

   ```
   var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.myEditor;
   if (editor) { editor.destroy(true); }
   CKEDITOR.config.forcePasteAsPlainText = false;
   CKEDITOR.config.width = 400;
   CKEDITOR.config.height = 300;

   CKEDITOR.replace('myEditor', CKEDITOR.config);
   ```